# What are the exact differences between Word Embedding and Word Vectorization?

Tags: nlp, word-embeddings, word2vec, text-classification, tfidf

I am learning NLP. I have tried to figure out the exact difference between Word Embedding and Word Vectorization. However, seems like some articles use these words interchangeably. But I think there must be some sort of differences.

In Vectorization, I came across these vectorizers:

> CountVectorizer, HashingVectorizer, TFIDFVectorizer

Moreover, while I was trying to understand the word embedding. I found these tools.

> Bag of words, Word2Vec

Would you please briefly summarize the differences and the algorithms of between Word Embeddings and Word Vectorization? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A „[bag of words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bag-of-words_model)“ usually describes encoding of text where one word (or ngram) is represented as one variable (column). This can be done as binary encoding or as count of words, often called [one-hot encoding](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html). Alternatively, you can introduce weights to represent the frequency of words in a document, such as [TFIDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf). See also [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html) for a sklearn implementation. Hashing essentially is a „bag of words“ using the [hashing trick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_hashing) to cope with previously unseen words in a corpus and a large (or growing) corpus.

In [word2vec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word2vec), each word is represented by a vector, which indicates how close one word is to another (this is the result of a pre-trained model). You can use a pre-trained word2vec model and assess the [proximity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21979970/how-to-use-word2vec-to-calculate-the-similarity-distance-by-giving-2-words) of words by comparing two (word) vectors e.g. based on the [Euclidean distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance). These vectors help models to better understand the (semantic) structure of some text via understanding the empirical co-occurance of words (which is not possible with one-hot encoding etc.)

[BERT](https://www.tensorflow.org/text/tutorials/classify_text_with_bert) goes even one step further. In BERT pre-training a word in a sentence is „masked“, where the model tries to predict the masked word in a sentence. Also „next sentence prediction“ is used to pre-train BERT models. By doing so, BERT has a even better ability to understand semantic relations in a text.

Answer (score 2):

I believe "embedding" is simply a subtype of "vectorization" where you use neural networks to learn the vectorization.

As stated by Peter above, you can vectorize a text without deep learning, but I don't think I've seen the word 'embedding' used in a non-deep learning context.

So vectorization refers to the general process of converting text or characters to a vector representation while embedding refers to learning the vectorization through deep learning (often through an embedding layer).